# sql query to fetch the records from a two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Table A

```
Id    pin    status   etc
1   11  FAILED  
2   22      
3   44      
4   55  FAILED
```

Table B

```
id   PIN      msg    counter
1    11      xyz         1
4    55      wsc         10
```

[image: img]

Table data:  I have 2 tables table A(status,id,pin as columns),table B(counter,id as columns)

I need a sql query to select the records where A.status =failed and also b.counter <10

In final result I need all those records with `a.status=failed` and `B.counter <10` and also fresh records which wont be present in table B.

But fresh records wont be present in table B so the b.counter <10 is not satisfied.

How do I handle this situation?

Comment: what do you mean by *fresh records*?

Comment: fresh recrods -->records which are present only in table A but not in Table B..

Comment: update you question adding a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting this correctly, you want to join tables A and B on the PIN column and you want records with A.status = failed and B.counter < 10.  But you also want records from table A that have no matching PIN in table B?

This may not be the most efficient query but it will get the job done, if I interpreted your requirements correctly.

```
SELECT *
  FROM A
 WHERE A.pin = B.pin
   AND A.status = 'FAILED'
   AND B.counter < 10
 UNION
SELECT *
  FROM A
 WHERE A.status = 'FAILED'
   AND A.pin NOT IN (SELECT pin FROM B);
```